# Method of finding inverse of a Matrix using minimal polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, inverse

Using a piece from my last [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252733/minimal-polynomial-determinants-and-invertibility) I want to show how to find $A^{-1}$ as a polynomial expression in $A$ of degree < $\deg m_A$ where the leading coefficient of the polynomial is $\dfrac{-1}{m_A(0)}$ where $m_A$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Comment: if $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial and $A$ is the matrix, what is $f(A)?$

Comment: $f(A) = 0$ correct? I am looking at a theorem in my book.

Comment: Yes. It is the lowest degree polynomial that does that. And it appears that you are calling the coefficient of $I$ in the minimal polynomial $m_A(0).$ Write it out, solve for $I,$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $m_A(x)=x^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ then since $m_A(A)=0$ implies
\begin{align*}
&A^m+a_{m-1}A^{m-1}+\cdots+a_1A+a_0I=0\\
&\implies a_0I=-(A^m+a_{m-1}A^{m-1}+\cdots+a_1A)\\
&\implies a_0I=A(-A^{m-1}-a_{m-1}A^{m-2}-\cdots-a_1)\\
&\implies I=A\left(-\dfrac{1}{a_0}A^{m-1}-\dfrac{a_{m-1}}{a_0}A^{m-2}-\cdots-\dfrac{a_1}{a_0}\right)\\
&\implies A^{-1}=-\dfrac{1}{a_0}A^{m-1}-\dfrac{a_{m-1}}{a_0}A^{m-2}-\cdots-\dfrac{a_1}{a_0}
\end{align*}