# Linear transformation is invertible if and only if $x$ does not divide its minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : V \to V$ be a linear transformation of a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ to itself. Prove that $T$ is invertible if and only if $x$ does not divide the minimal polynomial $m(x)$.

I don't really understand how to do this at all, so could someone show me a proof I can try to understand!

Comment: $T$ is invertible iff $0$ is not an eigen-value. What do eigen-values have to do with roots of the minimal polynomial?

Comment: All eigenvalues of T are roots of the minimal polynomial I think? Do you have a proof of this?

Comment: Okay got my proof of eigenvalues being roots of the minimal polynomial but how does it relate to x not dividing the minimal polynomial

Comment: $a$ is a root of a polynomial iff $(x-a)$ divides that polynomial.

Comment: Restated in terms of matrices, this has also been answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432124/minimal-polynomial-of-non-invertible-matrix and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252733/minimal-polynomial-determinants-and-invertibility (each of these threads gives one direction of the "if and only if").

Answer (score 5):

If $T$ satisfies any polynomial equation with non-zero (and therefore invertible) constant term, say $a_dT^d+\cdots+a_1T+a_0I=0$ with $a_0\neq 0$, you can rewrite this as
$$
  I=-\frac1{a_0}(a_dT^d+\cdots+a_1T)=-\frac1{a_0}(a_dT^{d-1}+\cdots+a_1T^0)T,
$$
which implies that $T$ is invertible; in particular this is the case if the minimal polynomial has a nonzero constant term. This part does not use the minimality of the minimum polynomial, but the other part does.

Suppose the minimal polynomial$~\mu_T$ has zero constant term (or equivalently that it is divisible by $X$), say
$$
  \mu_T=a_dX^d+\cdots+a_1X
$$
so that
$$
  0=a_dT^d+\cdots+a_1T=(a_dT^{d-1}+\cdots+a_1T^0)T.
$$
Now the expression in parentheses cannot be $0$ since it is a polynomial of degree$~d-1<\deg\mu_T$ in$~T$, but then $T$ cannot be invertible, for in that case the right hand side could not become$~0$.

One proves similarly that more generally $T-\lambda\operatorname{id}$ for some scalar$~\lambda$ is non-invertible (in other words that $\lambda$ is an eigenvlaue of$~T$) if and only if $X-\lambda$ divides$~\mu_T$.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution reached in comments:

1. An operator in  a finite-dimensional space is invertible iff $0$ is not its eigenvalue.
2. Eigenvalues are precisely the zeros of the minimal polynomial.
3. A polynomial $m$ is divisible by $x$ iff $m(0)=0$.