# Minimal polynomial of non-invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

> Assume that we have a non-invertible matrix $A\in \operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ with minimal polynomial $$\mu(t)=t^r+c_{r-1}t^{r-1}+\cdots+c_1t+c_0.$$
>   Show that the constant coefficient $c_0$ is $0$.

We know that $$\mu(A)=A^r+c_{r-1}A^{r-1}+\cdots+c_1A+c_0I=0,$$
but why does this yield $c_0 = 0$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the definition of a minimal polynomial, we know that $\mu(A) = 0$.  Note that for a matrix $M$, $\mu(M)$ means the matrix
$$
\mu(M) = 
M^r + c_{r-1}M^{r-1} + \cdots + c_1 M + c_0 I
$$
Note in particular that $c_0$ needs to be the coefficient of the identity matrix; at the very least, the expression $c_1 M + c_0$ makes no sense on its own.

With that out of the way, note that if $c_0 \neq 0$, we can rearrange $\mu(A) = 0$ to get
$$
-\frac 1{c_0}\left( A^r + c_{r-1}A^{r-1} + \cdots + c_1 A \right) = I
$$
Note that we can factor an $A$ out of the above expression.

Alternatively, note that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if the polynomial $(t-0)$ divides $\mu(t)$.

Comment: I edited my question, you were right about the "grammar", but I still don't see why $c_0$ is zero

Comment: I provide two ways of seeing it.  One is that if $c_0$ is not zero, we have an explicit expression for the inverse of $A$ (factor $A$ out of the above to find it).  The other is to note that $A$ is non-invertible if and only if $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.